# Change Form's error message class?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm new to CakePHP. I tried to change the default class `error-message` to `error` by following the [official docs](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Helpers/Form.html) this way:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Post', array(
    'inputDefaults' => array(
        'error' => array(
            'wrap' => 'small',
            'class' => 'error'
        )
    )
)); ?>
```

But when error occurred, it still uses the default `div.error-message`.

I also tried to set the code to each individual `input`. But still no effect:

```
$this->Form->input('title', array('error' => array('wrap' => 'small', 'class' => 'error')));
```

I'm using CakePHP 2.3.2

Any solution? Thanks

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri I set `isUnique` validation. But I don't think that matters right?

Answer (score 3):

Oops, I read the 1.3 Documentation which is not compatible with 2.3.

For version 2.0 above, we need to add `attributes` array inside the `error` array:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Post', array(
    'inputDefaults' => array(
        'error' => array(
            'attributes' => array(
                'wrap' => 'small', 'class' => 'error'
            )
        )
    )
)); ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: @DarCode thanks for supplying the answer yourself. Problems like this can take many hours to resolve if you're used to older versions of CakePHP. This question/answer may therefor be useful for other people as well